What caused Python 3.13-0b3 ( compiled with GIL disabled ) be slower than 3.12.0?
I did a simple performance test on python 3.12.0 against python 3.13.0b3 compiled with a --disable-gil flag. The program executes calculations of a Fibonacci sequence using ThreadPoolExecutor or ProcessPoolExecutor. The docs on the PEP introducing disabled GIL says that there is a bit of overhead mostly due to biased reference counting followed by per-object locking (https://peps.python.org/pep-0703/#performance). But it says the overhead on pyperformance benchmark suit is around 5-8%. My simple benchmark shows a significant difference in the performance. Indeed, python 3.13 without GIL utilize all CPUs
with a ThreadPoolExecutor but it is much slower than python 3.12 with GIL. Based on the CPU utilization and the elapsed time we can conclude that with python 3.13 we do multiple times more clock cycles comparing to the 3.12.
Program code:
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, ProcessPoolExecutor
import datetime
from functools import partial
import sys
import logging
import multiprocessing

logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(levelname)s: %(message)s',
)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
cpus = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
pool_executor = ProcessPoolExecutor if len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] == '1' else ThreadPoolExecutor
python_version_str = f'{sys.version_info.major}.{sys.version_info.minor}.{sys.version_info.micro}'
logger.info(f'Executor={pool_executor.__name__}, python={python_version_str}, cpus={cpus}')


def fibonacci(n: int) -> int:
    if n < 0:
        raise ValueError("Incorrect input")
    elif n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1 or n == 2:
        return 1
    else:
        return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)

start = datetime.datetime.now()

with pool_executor(8) as executor:
    for task_id in range(30):
        executor.submit(partial(fibonacci, 30))

    executor.shutdown(wait=True)

end = datetime.datetime.now()
elapsed = end - start
logger.info(f'Elapsed: {elapsed.total_seconds():.2f} seconds')

Test results:
# TEST Linux 5.15.0-58-generic, Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

INFO: Executor=ThreadPoolExecutor, python=3.12.0, cpus=2
INFO: Elapsed: 10.54 seconds

INFO: Executor=ProcessPoolExecutor, python=3.12.0, cpus=2
INFO: Elapsed: 4.33 seconds

INFO: Executor=ThreadPoolExecutor, python=3.13.0b3, cpus=2
INFO: Elapsed: 22.48 seconds

INFO: Executor=ProcessPoolExecutor, python=3.13.0b3, cpus=2
INFO: Elapsed: 22.03 seconds

Can anyone explain why do I experience such a difference when comparing the overhead to the one from pyperformance benchmark suit?
EDIT 1

I have tried with pool_executor(cpus) instead of pool_executor(8) -> still got the similar results.
I watched this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zWPe_CUR4yU and executed the following test: https://github.com/ArjanCodes/examples/blob/main/2024/gil/main.py

Results:
Version of python: 3.12.0a7 (main, Oct  8 2023, 12:41:37) [GCC 9.4.0]
GIL cannot be disabled
Single-threaded: 78498 primes in 6.67 seconds
Threaded: 78498 primes in 7.89 seconds
Multiprocessed: 78498 primes in 5.85 seconds

Version of python: 3.13.0b3 experimental free-threading build (heads/3.13.0b3:7b413952e8, Jul 27 2024, 11:19:31) [GCC 9.4.0]
GIL is disabled
Single-threaded: 78498 primes in 61.42 seconds
Threaded: 78498 primes in 32.29 seconds
Multiprocessed: 78498 primes in 39.85 seconds

so yet another test on my machine when we end up with multiple times slower performance. Btw. On the video we can see the similar overhead results as it is described in the PEP.
EDIT 2
As @ekhumoro suggested I did configure the build with the following flags:
 ./configure --disable-gil --enable-optimizations
and it seems the --enable-optimizations flag makes a significant difference in the considered benchmarks. The previous build was done with the following configuration:
./configure --with-pydebug --disable-gil.
Tests results:
Fibonacci benchmark:
INFO: Executor=ThreadPoolExecutor, python=3.12.0, cpus=2
INFO: Elapsed: 10.25 seconds

INFO: Executor=ProcessPoolExecutor, python=3.12.0, cpus=2
INFO: Elapsed: 4.27 seconds

INFO: Executor=ThreadPoolExecutor, python=3.13.0, cpus=2
INFO: Elapsed: 6.94 seconds

INFO: Executor=ProcessPoolExecutor, python=3.13.0, cpus=2
INFO: Elapsed: 6.94 seconds

Prime numbers benchmark:
Version of python: 3.12.0a7 (main, Oct  8 2023, 12:41:37) [GCC 9.4.0]
GIL cannot be disabled
Single-threaded: 78498 primes in 5.77 seconds
Threaded: 78498 primes in 7.21 seconds
Multiprocessed: 78498 primes in 3.23 seconds

Version of python: 3.13.0b3 experimental free-threading build (heads/3.13.0b3:7b413952e8, Aug  3 2024, 14:47:48) [GCC 9.4.0]
GIL is disabled
Single-threaded: 78498 primes in 7.99 seconds
Threaded: 78498 primes in 4.17 seconds
Multiprocessed: 78498 primes in 4.40 seconds

So the general gain from moving from python 3.12 multiprocessing to python 3.12 no-gil multi-threading are significant memory savings (we do have only a single process).
When we compare CPU overhead for the machine with only 2 cores:
[Fibonacci] Python 3.13 multi-threading against Python 3.12 multiprocessing: (6.94 - 4.27) / 4.27 * 100% ~= 63% overhead
[Prime numbers] Python 3.13 multi-threading against Python 3.12 multiprocessing: (4.17 - 3.23) / 3.23 * 100% ~= 29% overhead

I can only partially reproduce this on arch-linux using python-3.12.4 and python-3.13.0rc1 with linux-6.8.9 kernel. (My system has a AMD Ryzen 3 1200 Quad-Core CPU). Using your script, I get the following output: Py312 ThreadPoolExecutor 10.88 secs; Py312 ProcessPoolExecutor 1.44 secs; Py313 ThreadPoolExecutor 3.72 secs; Py313 ProcessPoolExecutor 3.84 secs. So about 3 times faster for thread-pool, but about 2.5 times slower for process-pool.

As a comparison, can you measure the performance in a single thread without using concurrent? Also, when spawning not greater processes than the number of CPU cores? (i.e. 2)

For me, when using a single thread: Py312 - 5.5 secs; Py313 - 15.1 secs. So this confirms the overhead of multi-threading, but still shows a 3 times slowdown for python-3.13. (Whether concurrent is used or not makes no significant difference).

Thanks for performing the test on your machines. I have updated the main post with some additional info in the "EDIT" section at the end of the message.

@K4liber I cannot reproduce your results using the linked test script. For me, single-threaded is about 25% slower, but multi-threaded is 4 times faster and multi-proc about equal. How did you install python-3.13? You should really compile the latest release-candidate with the standard python build-flags for your platform (plus --enable-optimizations and --disable-gil). You can display the current flags like this: python3.13 -c 'import sysconfig; print(" ".join(sysconfig.get_config_var( "CONFIG_ARGS").split()))'.

@ekhumoro thanks! I did miss the flag --enable-optimizations. I have edited the main post. Please create the answer so we can underline the solution.

@K4liber No problem. A even more significant issue is that you tested with a debug build. I have now added answer regarding this.

From the latest question edits, it seems the version of Python-3.13 used for testing was built with debug mode enabled and without optimisations enabled. The former flag in particular can have a large impact on performance testing, whilst the latter will have a much smaller, but still significant, impact. In general, it's best to avoid drawing any conclusions about performance issues when testing with development builds of Python.

Thanks for the help. I am a bit embarrassed about the title of this post, sounds a bit passive-aggressive against CPython developers who made a great work with no-gil implementation. On the other hand, the title is kind of clickbait that can lead to increased number of developers testing the no-gil builds.

your code is highly recursive function that has exponential time complexity. Each call to fibonacci(30) might result in many redundant calculations. it is not an efficient way to calculate Fibonacci numbers and is primarily CPU-bound with high computational cost.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q83nN97LVOU

Yes, I didn't intend to make if efficient. For both python versions, the number of calculations to be performed is exactly the same. What differs is the number of clock cycles spent on reference counting.

GIL prevents multiple native threads from executing Python bytecode simultaneously. This makes multi-threaded CPU-bound tasks less efficient but simplifies memory management since only one thread can be executed at a time.   While removing the GIL allows for true parallelism, the associated overheads can outweigh the benefits for certain types of tasks, particularly those that are CPU-bound and involve frequent updates to shared state.

@gillbates FYI: the use of Generative AI to create answers or comments on SO is banned.

@ekhumoro this is my source - https://dev.to/ohdylan/understanding-pythons-global-interpreter-lock-gil-mechanism-benefits-and-limitations-4aha

@gillbates thanks for the information, I am familiar with the general concept. Still, I do wonder why there is such significant difference and not only a slight one as described in PEP. The answer is probably somewhere in the details of implementation with gil disabled and the different benchmarks.

you address the right thing, yet I would rather call this an inefficiency of immense overhead costs ( from a choice of a recursion-formulated processing ), which explodes both in EXPTIME and EXPSPACE ( as all "state-saving" data, for the recursion dive, has to be stored somewhere + in some additional, non-computing, just both store+retrieve overhead, times added to the resulting inefficiency ) not a computing cost. Order of tests in if/elif cases was rather an anti-pattern for performance, deflecting attention from any GIL-lock related issues. Anyway, GIL-is-dead, Long live the Python!
